# JavaApplet with LWJGL broke after update to 7u45

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

We have a Java Apllet, running without problems since several years. It uses LWJGL, all jars are signed with a proper certificate (NOT self signed).
After the last Java Update to u45, the applet crashes.

What we have done so far:

- Added Permissions: all-permissions to Manifest of all JARs
- Added pplication-Library-Allowable-Codebase: * to Manifest of all JARs
- Added Caller-Allowable-Codebase: * to Manifest of all JARs
- Added Codebase: * to Manifest of all JARs
- Different permutations of the above

I know there were some changes to the way the security warnings are configured, but (for now!) we don't care about the popups asking for permissions. first we want to make it work,

Here are all exeptions occuring inside the java console. the rest of the output seems ok:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$4.getPermissions(AppletLoader.java:1206)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:1319)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$2.run(AppletLoader.java:909)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadAllowedCodebases(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

And:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.run(AppletLoader.java:906)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.createImplementation(Sys.java:124)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:111)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTGLCanvas.<clinit>(AWTGLCanvas.java:87)
    at j2cad.d.c.k(Unknown Source)
    at j2cad.applet.J2CadApplet.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:1330)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$2.run(AppletLoader.java:909)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "org.lwjgl.util.Debug" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$4.run(LWJGLUtil.java:454)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$4.run(LWJGLUtil.java:452)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.getPrivilegedBoolean(LWJGLUtil.java:452)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.<clinit>(LWJGLUtil.java:265)
    ... 21 more
```

The first one occurs several times, the second one only once in the end of the log.

All suggestions are appreciated, the website is down for everybody who did the update!

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a creepy workaround to avoid this problem due to the AppletLoader from lwjgl_util_applet.jar that override the security context by replacing the default classLoader. So we need to patch it :

1 - Download the class [HERE](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl_util_applet/2.8.0/org/lwjgl/util/applet/AppletLoader.java/?v=source)

2 - Replace this:

```
classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls) {
```

with this:

```
classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()) {
```

this:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
Class appletClass = classLoader.loadClass(getParameter("al_main"));
```

with this:

```
Class appletClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(getParameter("al_main"));
```

and this :

```
urlconnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
```

with this :

```
urlconnection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
```

3 - Compile and override the .class of the lwjgl_util_applet.jar with the new one.

4 - Remove the signature of all your jars (if exist) and re-sign all with those atributes in the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Only: false
Application-Name: My app
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_16 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
```

5 - In the applet tag, put this :

```
<param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
<param name="codebase_lookup" value="true">
<param name="classloader_cache" value="false">
<param name="al_version" value="0.1">"
```

6 - (The creepy part) Put all the jars in the param "al_jars" in the param "archive" (just put a white space in al_jars),

7 - Clean your cache (java & browser) and set your java cache active (like the future users of your app),

8 - Run your applet and keep you fingers crossed.

Comment: Thanks, I already read your post on the lwjgl forum. especially the last part with the 500mb cach stopped me from trying so far. it is a quite active site used by our custumers, so we were a bit afraid to try. will give it a shot though, and keep the fingers crossed :)

Comment: I've just edited my post to give a solution to the cache problem, The applet works well now. Just need to set the DefaultUseCaches to true.